# AWS S3 Acceso denegado - 403 forbiden

Tags: aws, amazon-s3

Tengo una pagina web hecha con laravel y quiero utilizar AWS S3 puesto que necesito subir, bajar y eliminar archivos. Pero tengo problemas al intentar listar los archivos que tengo.

```
Storage::disk('s3')->files();
```

Resultandome esto:

```
Aws/S3/Exception/S3Exception with message 'Error executing "ListObjects" ...
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>3E43AE (truncated...)
```

Esta politica la cree con este [generador](http://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html).

```
{
  "Id": "Policy1559792599026",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1559792362196",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "user"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1559792596859",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "myuser"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Tambien desactive en mi bucket el bloqueo del acceso público a buckets y objetos concedido a través de políticas de bucket públicas nuevas.

Answer (score 0):

el problema parece que es:

1. Por la definición del usuario en la política
2. Por los permisos que tenga configurado el usuario que usas

Respuesta 1: En la política en la sección Principal > AWS reemplaza el nombre por el ARN del usuario, quedaría algo como esto:

```
     "Principal": {
          "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::87986514365465:user/myuser"
       }, 
     "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:ListBucket"
      ],
```

El ARN del usuario lo puedes conseguir dentro de consola web de AWS en: **IAM > Usuarios** Luego selecciona tu usuario y en la sección **Resumen** pueden ver **ARN de usuario**

Respuesta 2: Debes chequear que el usuario que estás usando tenga asignado los permisos a los haces referencia en la política: **s3:GetObjetc** y **s3:ListBucket** , eso lo puedes chequear en la consola web de AWS: **IAM > Usuarios** Luego selecciona tu usuario y luego en la pestaña **Permisos** verifica que en la tabla estén asignados los permisos mencionados anteriormente

Answer (score 0):

Dos soluciones (dependiendo cuál sea tu escenario):

1. Si estás accediendo al bucket via una `EC2` donde tenés tu página web, fíjate que la `EC2` tenga asignado un rol y que dicho rol tenga asignado esta política:

```
"Action": [
    "s3:GetObject",
    "s3:ListBucket"
]
```

Esto lo puedes ver desde `IAM` y buscar el rol que tengas asignado. En caso de no tener asignado un rol deberías configurar uno con los permisos necesarios (en este caso de `get and list` a `s3`) todo esto en `IAM`.

2. En caso que estés accediendo con tu usuario a la pagina web (via `cli`, `sdk`, `sam`, etc). Tu usuario debe tener asignada la política:

```
"Action": [
    "s3:GetObject",
    "s3:ListBucket"
]
```

O posiblemente te has asignado un rol que contienen dicha política o asignado un grupo y al grupo le han asignado dicho rol. Puedes consultar todo esto en `IAM`. En caso de que no tengas configurado nada de lo anterior, te recomendaría que lo hagas y así sigas las buenas prácticas en [IAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html).